# Change gamepad bindings on PC for dragon age inquisition

Tags: pc, dragon-age-inquisition

I know there have been similar postings regarding the location of the gamepad bindings...however, is there a way to change the gamepad bindings on PC? In the game options, I can only change the bindings when using mouse & keyboard, but not for a gamepad, and when using the gamepad, the bindings section is Locked (meaning there is a Locked symbol, and no way to access it)...when I'm trying to scan an area with the LS, the screen constantly moves between my party members as well since these functions both use the LS. Is there a way to "lock" the scan to make it automatic, or change the binding for this? In the meantime, I find that I have to change over to M&K just to scan an area, and it's a huge pain to constantly go back and forth between the game interaction methods.